# Update object property values and push them into array in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to update properties on an object while looping through the new values and pushing them into an array, I am a bit confused on how to do this. I would like to start from a default object on which only some of the property values need to get changed.

I created 2 arrays with new values to update the default object with, when I log the updated person separately `console.log(defaultPerson)`, the output I expected gets printed (the person with updated name and hair color). I expected that pushing the updated person into an array at the end of the loop would push the value that gets printed when logging.

```js
// the default object
const defaultPerson = {
  name: "default",
  address: "Some street",
  hair: {
    color: "default",
  }
}

// new values to update
const newNames = ["Alexander", "Hendrik", "Stephan"];
const newHairColors = ["brown", "brown", "black"];

const updatedPeople = []; // array for updated people

for(let i = 0; i < newNames.length; i++) {
  defaultPerson.name = newNames[i];
  defaultPerson.hair.color = newHairColors[i];
  
  console.log(defaultPerson); // logs the updated object
  updatedPeople.push(defaultPerson); // pushes last values 3 times
}

console.log("Print array");
updatedPeople.forEach(p => console.log(p));
```

This does not seem to be the case, instead the values inside the array are 3 times the object updated with the last value from the new values array (Stephan, black).

I figured creating a new object inside the loop and setting it equal to the spread default object and then update its values could be a solution. That way every loop, a new object is created and gets its values updated before pushing it in the array. This works, but only on the `name` value of the person, `hair.color` still stays the same, this is probably because hair is another nested object and so it goes on.

```js
// the default object
const defaultPerson = {
  name: "default",
  address: "Some street",
  hair: {
    color: "default",
  }
}

// new values to update
const newNames = ["Alexander", "Hendrik", "Stephan"];
const newHairColors = ["brown", "brown", "black"];

const updatedPeople = []; // array for updated people

for (let i = 0; i < newNames.length; i++) {
  const newPerson = { ...defaultPerson }; // spread
  newPerson.name = newNames[i];
  newPerson.hair.color = newHairColors[i];

  updatedPeople.push(newPerson);
}

updatedPeople.forEach(p => console.log(p));
```

Comment: Yes, `hair` is its own object and must be cloned as well. Was that your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than pushing, I'd just `map` the array of names into an array of "person" objects. Note that this works only because `newHairColors` has the same length as `newNames`.

```js
// the default object
const defaultPerson = {
  name: "default",
  address: "Some street",
  hair: {
    color: "default",
  }
}

// new values to update
const newNames = ["Alexander", "Hendrik", "Stephan"];
const newHairColors = ["brown", "brown", "black"];

const updatedPeople = newNames.map((newName, i) => ({
   ...defaultPerson,
   name: newName,
   hair: {
      ...defaultPerson.hair,
      color: newHairColors[i]
   }
}));

updatedPeople.forEach(p => console.log(p));
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks nice and neat, if I would like to keep the for loop logic can I also just spread `hair` out further and do it like that?

Comment: Yeah, just use the same code you have, with the `hair` spread.